# Crossed stem plot in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to reproduce in Matlab a plot that looks like this:

[image]

The stem3 plot command sounds nice but only for the vertical stems. Not the second series with the horizontal ones.

Everything would be easy if I could plot using the usual commands and rotate the result.

Comment: Well you can use the command `fill3()` to get a 3D plot filled with colours for 2 different 3D sets of data. But when i tried it for some reasons the two datas while using the same x-axis had an angle between them. I used `fill3([x_2 20], [y_2 0], [z_2 0], 'g', x_1,y_1,z_1, 'r' )` To correct it. My x-axis ranges from 0 to 20 thats why the correction fits the last point to (20/0/0). Unfortunately i have no idea how to make it with bars as the given graph above.

Answer (score 2):

How a about this? Manually plot each line in 3D stemming from the `x` axis:

```
x = 0:.01:2*pi*3;
z = sin(x);
y = -sin(x);

hold on
for n = 1:numel(x);
    plot3([x(n) x(n)], [0 y(n)], [0 0], 'r');
    plot3([x(n) x(n)], [0 0], [0 z(n)], 'b');
end
view(15,25)
```

[image]

---

As noted by @TheMinion, it's easier to use `fill3`:

```
x = 0:.01:2*pi*3;
z = sin(x);
y = -sin(x);

fill3(x,y,zeros(size(x)),'r')
hold on
fill3(x,zeros(size(x)),z,'b')
view(15,25)
```

Comment: i think its easier to just use the `fill3` command as given above as comment. As i said there it isn't a problem to fill the lines but to fill one and the other only with drawn lines is more complicated. I think you would have to change your code and do quite a bit of work and at the end you would have most likely a code only really nice for that poject.